# HMAC SHA256 walkthrough examples

Tags: hmac, sha-256, mac

I'm trying to implement HMAC SHA256 (I've implemented SHA256 successfully).

I am trying to find examples where they show the results after each HMAC stage (XOR, append, H etc).

Does anyone know of any resources which contain examples with the results from each step?

Comment: "Date" is just the singular form of "data" here, derived from the Latin "datum": *a given, or that which we take for granted and use as the basis of our calculations*. It's not a date in the temporal sense.

Comment: I've found the basic wiki [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) to be sufficient as it has the workflow. And you can verify against the test inputs. It's really not that hard if you use a proven version of the hash rather than writing that bit yourself.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes-onstrike I'm pretty sure it's a typo, and "Input data" is what's intended. (Datum is the singular form of data btw.)

Comment: You can get test data from the [Nist](https://csrc.nist.gov/projects/cryptographic-standards-and-guidelines/example-values), see [here for HMAC-SHA256](https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/Projects/Cryptographic-Standards-and-Guidelines/documents/examples/HMAC_SHA256.pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I have been in this situation, I have found it helpful to find someone else's implementation, and instrument it with print statements. It's not clear what langauge you are using, but it never hurts to get exposed to a new one anyway :).  Take this example in C perhaps? https://github.com/h5p9sl/hmac_sha256/blob/master/hmac_sha256.c